# react components does not refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm making a react app where i have to update a list twice (at least or more). Obviously i have to use useState hook for being able to edit that list whenever i want. That's pretty easy, but the problem is that i don't really know but in my app, the two lists fusion themselves. Here's an example: i have a fruit list `["apples", "bananas", "avocados"]` and a social network one `["instagram", "snapchat", "facebook", "whatsapp", "telegram"]`. Now, when i change the state to the first list it becomes exactly: `["apples", "bananas", "avocados", "whatsapp", "telegram"]`. And that's really weird. Instead of a set it makes a somelike difference(?). By the way, here's some simplified code of what i wrote (the essential):

```
// Initialize in the App function

const [colors, setColors] = useState([])
const [colorpicker,setColorPicker] = useState(null)
const [inputskin, setInputSkin] = useState(localStorage.getItem('skin') !== null ? localStorage.getItem('skin') : testskin)

const inputFile = useRef(null) // rename as inputSkin

useEffect(() => {
    const allcolors = []
    async function getPixels(){
        console.log('changed input skin')
        const image = await pixels(inputskin)
        for(let i = 0; i < image.height; i++){
            pixelLoop:
            for(let j = 0; j < image.width; j++){
                const color = []

                for(let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    color.push(image.data[(i * image.width + j) * 4 + k])
                }

                const hex = rgbToHex(color)

                for (let clr of allcolors) if (clr[0] === hex) { clr[1]++; continue pixelLoop }
                if (!(allcolors.includes(hex)) && color[3] != 0) allcolors.push([hex,0])
            }
        }
        allcolors.sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1])
        
        setColors(allcolors)
        console.log(allcolors)
    }
    getPixels()
    changePalette = setColorPicker
}, [inputskin])
```

I really can't figure out what's the problem because when i console log the colors array, that's okay, it shows me the array that i want to have in the render, but in the render it basically does not refresh itself. I tried removing by DOM the children of the components nodes, but this does not really help. Here's how i render the components:

```
// render
return(
    ...
    { colors.map(([color], i) => <Color colorstart = { color } id = { i } key = { i } colorChange = { colorChange } />) }
    ...
)
```

Here's when i load the first color array:
[image]

And here's when i load the second color array:
[image]

Here's what i would expect to have when i load the second array (I obtain this only if i reload the page):

[image]

As you can see it eats the first two color rows :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting *key* property in the *map* function which probably causes the problem. Set unique key property in

```
<Color colorstart = { color } id = { i } colorChange = { colorChange } />
```

for example

```
<Color key={color[0]} colorstart = { color } id = { i } colorChange = { colorChange } />
```

and check if it helps.
Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Edit: ok no I tried to add key with the integer for loop it and it is not unique. So really thanks